# ASP.NET Server Error in '/' Application in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am working on asp.net website in visual studio 2012. My application is running but on log in page that is inherited from master page when i use validations. It display this error like this

"**Server Error in '/' Application.**

WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive)."

I got help from Google to include these code in web.config

but when I write this code to web.config file it display another Exception that is

"**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."
Please any one help what to do with error I will be thank full for him/her.
Thank you 
Husnain Aslam

Comment: What changes did you make to the web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either disable unobtrusive validation in web.config

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
...
</configuration>
```

or add a mapping for jquery (case sensitive) to ScriptManager in global.asax and **use** unobtrusive validation

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery",
   New ScriptResourceDefinition With
   { .Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" })
End Sub
```

or use nuget to automatically add the above

```
Install-Package AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery
```